# How would I use the following code as a function in python?

Tags: python, function

```
a = int(input('Enter the number:'))
list=[]
for i in range(1,a+1):
    if (a%i==0):
        list.append(i)
print(list)
print(sum(list))
```

Here in this code, I tried to find out the divisor of a given number, then print the divisors and lastly the sum of the divisors. What I need is to put this as a function to call it for future uses.

Comment: What problem are you having turning it into a function?

Comment: Take a look at the Python docs on [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Here in this code, I tried to find out the divisor of a given number, then print the divisors and lastly the sum of the divisors. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def my_func(val):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1,val+1):
        if (val%i==0):
            lst.append(i)
    return lst, sum(lst)
```

Now you can simply call your function like this:

```
a = int(input('Enter the number:'))
lst, lst_summ = my_func(a)
print(lst)
print(lst_summ)
```

Also, it is not good practice to use built in functions as variable names. `list` is a built in function.

Comment: Thank you so much.